# Why is my ground so dark?

Tags: xna, c#, 3d

I wanted to add a ground so I can know the position of a helicopter in the world. But the ground appeared in a weird way:

[image]

The ground had the following texture:

[image]

This is the code:

```
public class ImportModel
{
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
    public Vector3 Rotation { get; set; }
    public Vector3 Scale { get; set; }
    Model Model;
    Matrix[] modeltransforms;
    GraphicsDevice GraphicDevice;
    ContentManager Content;
    BoundingSphere sphere;
    bool boundingimplemented = false;
    public ImportModel(string model, GraphicsDevice gd, ContentManager cm, Vector3 position, Vector3 rot, Vector3 sca)
    {
        GraphicDevice = gd;
        Content = cm;
        Position = position;
        Rotation = rot;
        Scale = sca;
        Model = Content.Load<Model>(model);
        modeltransforms = new Matrix[Model.Bones.Count];
        Model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(modeltransforms);
    }
    public void Draw(Camera camera)
    {
        Matrix baseworld = Matrix.CreateScale(Scale) * Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(Rotation.Y, Rotation.X, Rotation.Z) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Model.Meshes)
        {
            Matrix localworld = modeltransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * baseworld;
            foreach (ModelMeshPart meshpart in mesh.MeshParts)
            {
                BasicEffect effect = (BasicEffect)meshpart.Effect;
                effect.World = localworld;
                effect.View = camera.View;
                effect.Projection = camera.Projection;
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
    public BoundingSphere BoundingSphere
    {
        get
        {
            if (!boundingimplemented)
            {
                foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Model.Meshes)
                {
                    BoundingSphere transformed = mesh.BoundingSphere.Transform(
                    modeltransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index]);
                    sphere = BoundingSphere.CreateMerged(sphere, transformed);
                }
                Matrix worldTransform = Matrix.CreateScale(Scale) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);
                BoundingSphere transforme = sphere;
                transforme = transforme.Transform(worldTransform);
                return transforme;
            }
            else
            {
                Matrix worldTransform = Matrix.CreateScale(Scale) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);
                BoundingSphere transformed = sphere;
                transformed = transformed.Transform(worldTransform);
                return transformed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I call the class from the Game1 class:

```
ImportModel ground = new ImportModel("ground", GraphicsDevice, Content, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Zero, new Vector3(20f));
```

This is how the scene looks from top:

[image]

Comment: nobody's going to help you if you don't post any code, even the pictures you posted are terribly lit, if lit at all actually, light the scene properly and point the camera at the ground so people can see what's going on, and post your rendering code

Comment: ok i may be missing something, but have you even set the texture?

Comment: I used the ground.x from this sample http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/avatar_shadows

Answer (score 1):

You must set `effect.Texture` to a `Texture2D` object that contains your checkers texture and you have previously loaded with the `ContentManager`.